# how to get queue information from asterisk

Tags: sip, asterisk, pbx, elastix

I am running asterisk on a elastix 2.2 distro. I have a Queue with EXT 9000 where 3 softphone (c#) extensions belong to this round robin queue.

I know that I could trigger a AGI or AMI event from the dialplan and let in some way a webservice know about the length of the queue and then forward this information to the softphones.

Is there any way that the softphones could get this information directly from asterisk. Either something AsteriskBuiltIn or ElastixBuiltIn.

a last resort (baaaaaad) idea was to open a line, call an encoded number like (555*1) and receive back a dtmf. it is a Bad Way but it would work.

Open for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Queue drop events into ami.

Also queue log all actions into /var/log/asterisk/queue_log, which is posible put to mysql(see [this](http://work.mikeboylan.com/posts/2012/03/asterisk-queuelog-to-mysql.html))

There are no way say how your softphone can catch that event. But for sure you can get that info from mysql and rewrite your softphones to show that info.

Also elastix call center edition have web panel for call center. As option you can check fop2 project for panel.